# What can be inferred about the training data from a trained neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, datasets

Suppose we trained a neural network on some training set that we call $X$.

Given the neural network and the method of training(algorithm, hyperparameters etc.) can we infer anything about $X$.

Now, instead, suppose we also have some subset of the training data $Y \in X$ available. Is there anything we can infer about $Y^c$?

Comment: What you refer with $Y^c$?

Comment: And should this belong to DataScience SE site?

Comment: @mico I don't really think so. This is a conceptual question about neural networks.

Comment: @mico the complement of Y in X

Comment: @Dilitante You're asking two questions here. I would ask just one. I think it is already pretty difficult to answer your first vague question. What do you mean by "conclusion"? We could e.g. conclude that $X$ is the training dataset, but, of course, this is not what you're looking for, so, please, try to be more specific.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that $X$ is unknown

Comment: The impression I got from the question is that you're curious if, for example, personally sensitive information may "leak" from training data into the trained neural network's weights, and may still partially be reconstructed by a third party with access to the NN weights but no access to the original training data? I definitely know that this is a thing, there are people doing research on this (and on how to train models such that there is no risk of leaking personal data to users of the trained model)... but I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to write a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, along those lines. I heard someone make a comment that GDPR could mean models must be retrained when the data they were originally trained on is no longer allowed to be kept. At first I thought they were confused.